# Make two relative layout float right and left

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a simple question.
I have made two relative layout , one contains image, other contains text.
I want them to float to left and right respectively.
Image layout should take 40% width whereas the text layout should have 60%.

How can i acheieve this?
My xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#cccccc">

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#eaeaea">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:src="@drawable/mike"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#fa6800">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:text="email"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello This is testing"
            android:id="@+id/guid"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"
            android:text="name:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!-- Email label -->

        <!-- Mobile number label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Mobile: "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change `android:orientation` to `horizontal` and add `layout_weight=4` for the `RelativeLayout` on the left, and 6 for the one on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it in a LinearLayout with horiznotal orientation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#cccccc">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:weight="4"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#eaeaea">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:src="@drawable/mike"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:weight="6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#fa6800">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:text="email"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello This is testing"
            android:id="@+id/guid"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"
            android:text="name:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!-- Email label -->

        <!-- Mobile number label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Mobile: "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the texts in the other realtive layout are all overlapped. why is that so?

Comment: In a relativelayout you need to tell a textview to be to the right of another one (relative to that one or parent or another view... that's what relative layout is for anyway) otherwise things like overlapping happen. See here for a quick google's sample http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html